# MySQL table1 and table2 if not exist in table 1 show

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a sql command which selects everything from one table but if there is already a record of this in table2 it doesn't show these records. Now I want to filter this based on user_id as well. So only filter it based on the user_id that is viewing the page. I got the variables all sorted out, just have to implement it into mysql. (The parent_id is necessary cause it contains subcategories which have levels each level corresponds with its level)

Table1:

```
ID, user_id, table2_id
```

Table2:

```
ID, naam, parent_id
```

My query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM   table2
WHERE parent_id = $d  &&  NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  null 
        FROM   table2
        WHERE   table2.table1_id = table1.id  
        )
```

I'm going to try to clarify it with an example.

Table1 has the following records:

```
ID: 1, User_ID 2, table2_id 3
ID: 2, User_id 2, table2_id 4
ID: 3, User_id 3, table2_id 4
ID: 4, User_id 3, table2_id 9
```

Table2:

```
ID: 1, Naam: Test, Parent_ID 1
ID: 2, Naam: Test2, Parent_ID 1
ID: 3, Naam: Test3, Parent_ID 1
ID: 4, Naam: Test4, Parent_ID 1
ID: 9, Naam: Test9, Parent_ID 1
```

So if USER_ID = 2 I want to show everything from table2 not associated with user 2. This would mean I would like the following records: ID1 (test), ID2 (test2) and ID9 (test9).

Sorry for the confusing explanation and any help is appreciated.

Comment: I begrijp niet wat je hier wil zeggen: **(The parent_id is necessary cause it contains subcategories which have levels each level corresponds with its level)**. Geef misschien even de tekst in het Nederlands, dan vertaal ik het wel!

Comment: For all who don't understand @user3144770 's  comment, he's going to translate for OP, to make it more understandable for everyone.

Comment: Ehm ok blijft lastig uit te leggen haha. Ik ga het dus maar vanaf het begin proberen. Ik heb een chained select form. Deze form haalt informatie op uit de database. Ik heb hierin hoofd categorieën en sub categorieën in dezelfde table. de parent_id houd bij bij wie deze hoord (1 staat voor bijv hoofdcategorie test)

Als een user al een entry heeft voor een bepaalde categorie wil ik deze eruit filteren.Dus feitelijk wil ik alleen de records zien die nog niet geassocieerd zijn met die persoon

Comment: Answer of zedfoxus did the trick thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a query like this:

```
select * from table2
where not exists (
  select 1 from table1
  where user_id = 2
  and table2.id = table2_id
);
```

Tables:

```
create table table1 (id int, user_id int, table2_id int);
insert into table1 values (1,2,3), (2,2,4), (3,3,4), (4,3,9);

create table table2 (id int, naam varchar(10), parent_id int);
insert into table2 values
(1, 'test', 1),
(2, 'test2', 1),
(3, 'test3', 1),
(4, 'test4', 1),
(9, 'test9', 1);
```

Result:

```
| id |  naam | parent_id |
|----|-------|-----------|
|  1 |  test |         1 |
|  2 | test2 |         1 |
|  9 | test9 |         1 |
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06339/3